# Earned 'Civic Duty' but Votes in profile did not update

Tags: support, badges

I just earned the 'Civic Duty' badge for voting 300 times. However the indicator showing the 'votes cast' did not change.

See the screenshot below.
[image]

The screenshot was taken from a different browser, so it is not a browser cache issue.

I 'think', that I have read somewhere, that votes are not immediately assigned but some time should pass first, but I am not sure if I remember well or if this is the case.

**Update**
The 'votes cast' was updated after almost 2 hours.

Comment: I think its just *Votes Cast* did not update. Wait for some time .

Comment: @SKD I know that (20mins almost passed). Isn't this considered as a bug, even if it minor?

Comment: Yea it is a bug. Vote counts doesn't get updated at the time you vote. Even I have also experienced this.  (note- I am not the downvoter)

Comment: Blame caching. It will probably update in a while.

Comment: Some of the profile details are only updated periodically by scripts that run at specific intervals or at specific times.  And other details are slow to update because some views are cached server-side for performance reasons (IIRC much of the profile page is cached).  If it is due to one of these issues then it is definitely not a bug, but just an implementation side-effect.

Comment: @psubsee2003 I was partially aware of something like that. As I said, I do not know / not sure is this is the case here. So I reported it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The case here as described in the comments is the that the scripts update the information periodically, not immediately since that will be a lot of work on the servers. [Caching is to blame](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/) and 20 minutes might be a little short. Wait a bit longer, maybe about 40 more minutes then the votes cast should be updated. As correctly said by psubsee2003:

> Some of the profile details are only updated periodically by scripts that run at specific intervals or at specific times. And other details are slow to update because some views are cached server-side for performance reasons (IIRC much of the profile page is cached). If it is due to one of these issues then it is definitely not a bug, but just an implementation side-effect

Comment: This past week, 1 hr is way too short.  I think the figure is in the multiple hours now.  Not complaining, just noticing how slow it is getting (which is what brought me to this question).